# Recording on database the time of a page view

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, session, time

i build a site (in PHP) where the users register and then access to reserved Powerpoint presentations. The owner told me to record the time users spend on viewing presentation, but i don't know how to display and record this kind of data. I think that JS and AJAX could help me, but i don't know what script can i use to do that.
Thank you in advice for your opinions and help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

basically you should trigger a php script when the user closes the powerpoint presentation, and this can be achieved for example opening the presentation in a modal window and force the user to click on a "close" button to terminate the presentation.

Another solution may be to open the presentation in a new window (even if is not so elegant) and use this script to trigger and action when the window onunload event is triggered:

```
    <a>Click me!</a>

window.onclick = function() {
    var win = window.open("/");
    win.onload = function() {
        console.log("onload");
        win.onunload = function() {
            alert("onunload");
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this help.